# Como lidar com banco de dados trabalhando com docker?

Tags: sql, wordpress, github, docker

Comecei a trabalhar com `docker` recentemente e eis uma dúvida e em uma preparação para um ambiente `wordpress lamp` , me deparei com subir meu banco e meus arquivos .

A ideia era deixa tudo dentro de um repositório dentro do `git-hub` que eu pudesse clona partir de qualquer lugar criar a imagem e restabelecer o meu site, porém o repositório do `git-hub` tem um limite de 100 megas.

Como posso trabalhar de forma eficaz com o banco nesses casos usando o docker?

Tem que fazer parte de uma imagem para upar para o servidor ou trato o `sql` a parte?

Comment: Sua dúvida seria qual a forma ideal de versionar tua imagem Docker?

Comment: Quando está trabalhando com docker para ter um conteiner de um wordpress, a forma correta de trabalhar com o banco de dados seria ele fazer parte da imagem ? pq estou estudando estes codigos de um docker -compose e no caso ele cria a imagem. A minha dúvida é se eu trabalho assim sempre em cima desse script que prepara tudo e cria a imagem e sobe o banco ou como vc disse manter-lo direto na imagem.

por exemplo, eu pensei em manter tudo no github mas ele nao suporta o arquivo do banco , porque é muito grande.

Comment: Assim, vou comentar aqui por se tratar da minha opinião. Eu faria no Dockerfile a criação do banco, mas ficaria num container diferente do da aplicação. Tem um padrão chamado data-only container que recomenda essa separação: http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não faz sentido ter o BD em imagem, o que você terá será o serviço de BD, e não o banco em si!

Você deverá ter o banco em um docker de file system, e deverá fazer backups regulares apartir da ferramenta própria de banco de dados.

Em caso de desastre o banco será recuperado através do backup, e não de uma imagem.

Bancos de dados executam transações, cálculos, etc... A ferramenta de banco de dados tem a inteligência para não deixar a transação parar no meio do caminho. E também tem o fato de que é possível dependendo do banco fazer backups online de transações, ou seja, a cada 15 minutos você pode ter um backup, em caso de disastre a possibilidade é de que se perca apenas 15 minutos de transação, esse tipo de feature você não tem em uma imagem.